# How can I mod_rewrite all incoming URLs except certain specific ones?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite URLs where there are a few fixed page URLs, and everything else gets rewritten. Here's what I need:

```
domain.com/
domain.com/about
domain.com/* (anything else)
```

Should redirect to:

```
/index.php
/about.php
/display.php?id=*
```

No idea how to do it. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Exactly as you wrote it, using [`L` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html) on the first two rules.

Comment: Exactly as I wrote what? Sorry...??

Comment: Using three rules, in that order, and preventing the third rule to trigger in first two cases by the use of the L flag. (You did read the link, yes?)

Comment: Perhaps I should explain more:
RewriteRule ^about$ /about.php [L]
is easy and it works fine. But it's the only thing I can get to work. I can't find a way to do this with the index page since there is nothing in the URL to do a regex match on. It loops back to itself and goes to /display.php?id=display.php

Comment: "I can't find a way to do this with the index page since there is nothing in the URL to do a regex match on." If regexp `^about$` matches `about`, what does `^$` match?

Answer (score 2):

Solved! This works:

```
RewriteRule ^about$ /about.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /display.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The index page is handled by using (.+) instead of (.*), which lets the site config forward the request normally to index.php so .htaccess doesn't try and forward it to display.php.

Comment: That also works, though I was trying to get you to `RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L]` :D